# Unable to search my answers for a particular topic

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, search

In an effort to find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253928), I executed [this query](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13854+title%3Auncertainty). I tried several other variants of this query, but I was unable to find my answer to a question about uncertainty. I thought I used to be able to perform this type of search, but whether that is the case, I would really like to be able to search for my answers on a given topic.

Comment: I'd guess the issue is that the word "uncertainty" does not appear *in your answer*. I do agree that this behaviour should be changed.

Comment: This alongside your avatar makes you seem *very* dissatisfied with the software. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search of `user:13854 uncertainty` would now yield the expected results.  In quite a few cases we're seeing come up, searching titles on answers specifically when searching within a user's posts makes a lot of sense.  A change that does just that was deployed a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the notice :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's the first link google brings up for

[uncertainty robjohn site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=uncertainty%20robjohn%20site%3amath.stackexchange.com)

I've found that google almost always beats the internal search here.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using Google for searching on SE because of this bug(?), but it would be nice if our internal search worked, too.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/100677/) which searches for your answers to questions with given keyword in the title. The results are shown in reverse chronological order, with a snippet of content to help in locating the answer you are looking for.

The keyword should be entered in lower case, since it is matched to `LOWER(Title)`

Comment: Note that for logged-in users the field UserId is pre-filled, so one only enters the keyword(s). Just as easy as any search.